# How to Convert MYSQL Latin-1 GEOMETRY field to UTF8 to get it to work with Django?

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, geodjango, iso-8859-1

Trying to cast the field back onto itself throws the following error.

```
UPDATE <table> SET geo_field = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(geo_field USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8); 

[Err] 1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

I'm trying to use django 1.9 to datadump json and it keeps choking on the latin-1 chars.

I'm using the mysql.gis backend.

Trying to use a raw cursor in python didn't work either.

```
def convert_latin_uft8(badfields, table, host, user, passwd, db ):
    import MySQLdb
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, db=db)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `{0}`;".format(table))
    for item in cur.fetchall():
        for field in badfields:
            data =item[field].decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
            print data
```

I'm stuck.  Any help woud be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `paths` field had the improper model type set.

`paths = models.PolygonField()`

Worked like a CHARM!